# How do I calculate the next annual occurrence of a date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given a Ruby date, does a one liner exist for calculating the next anniversary of that date?

For example, if the date is May 01, 2011 the next anniversary would be May 01, 2012, however if it is December 01, 2011, the next anniversary is December 01, 2011 (as that date hasn't yet arrived).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excellent gem exists for doing this called recurrence. You can checkout the source code or some samples:

- https://github.com/fnando/recurrence
- http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/tag/recurrence/

For example, if you have a `date` set you could try:

```
date = ...
recurrence = Recurrence.new(every: :year, on: [date.month, date.day])
puts recurrence.next
```

Answer (score 2):

If you `date` variable is an instance of `Date` then you can use [`>>`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/Date.html#M000393):

> Return a new Date object that is n months later than the current one.

So you could do this:

```
one_year_later = date >> 12
```

The same approach applies to [DateTime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/DateTime.html). If all you have is a string, then you can use the [`parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/Date.html#M000358) method:

```
next_year        =  Date.parse('May 01, 2011') >> 12
next_year_string = (Date.parse('May 01, 2011') >> 12).to_s
```

IMHO you're better off using the date libraries (Date and DateTime) as much as possible but you can use the Rails extensions (such as `1.year`) if you know that Rails will always be around or you don't mind manually pulling in active_support as needed.

Comment: Rails extends Date, DateTime and Time so anything handled in the lower libraries will be propagated upwards. See [Extensions to Date](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-date)

Comment: @Tin Man: I'm talking about the Fixnum additions such as `1.year` and `12.months`, not the Date or DateTime additions.

Comment: The leap-year calculations are part of Date. `1.year` and the like are extensions to Float, at least that is the class returned, but the adjustments happen in Date, so it works correctly. `Date.parse('feb 29, 2000') + 1.year
# => Wed, 28 Feb 2001`. If it didn't work Rails would be a failure for anything involving Date math, and we know that isn't the case.

Comment: @Tin Man: Right. The `year` et al methods are extensions to Fixnum but they do return Float and Rails actually gets the date arithmetic right so I'll pull that criticism. I still think you're better off using the standard libraries as much as possible though. Thanks for the quick education.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Ruby's Date class:

```
the_date = Date.parse('jan 1, 2011')
(the_date < Date.today) ? the_date + 365 : the_date # => Sun, 01 Jan 2012

the_date = Date.parse('dec 31, 2011')
(the_date < Date.today) ? the_date.next_year : the_date # => Sat, 31 Dec 2011
```

Or, for convenience use ActiveSupport's [Date class extensions](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-date):

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/date/calculations'
the_date = Date.parse('jan 1, 2011')
(the_date < Date.today) ? the_date.next_year : the_date # => Sun, 01 Jan 2012
the_date = Date.parse('dec 31, 2011')
(the_date < Date.today) ? the_date.next_year : the_date # => Sat, 31 Dec 2011
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def next_anniversary(d)
  Date.today > d ? 1.year.from_now(d) : d
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Pulling in a gem just to do this is overkill.

```
your_date > Date.today ? your_date : your_date >> 12
```

Comment: Two downvotes - sure would be helpful to have some comments as to why?  I thought this would be a helpful response.